# gulp src and destination is not injecting into my index.html file

Tags: npm, gulp, bower, gulp-inject, wiredep

So when I have a project that has the gulpfile in the same folder as my index.html

but Now that I have a project in which I want the gulpfile.js inside a folder and the root of my project has the index.html  ( yes with all the correct tags)

**Same folder this works**

```
return gulp.src('*.html')
.pipe(wiredep(options))
.pipe(inject(injectSrc, injectOptions))
.pipe(gulp.dest(''));
```

**index.html is now back outside the gulp file directory**

```
return gulp.src('*.html')
.pipe(wiredep(options))
.pipe(inject(injectSrc, injectOptions))
.pipe(gulp.dest('../index.html'));
```

I gather that I don't understand the  `src` and `dest` of gulp  , what am i needing to do?

Answer (score 0):

i think your param for `gulp.dest` will be a 'folder', not a 'file' path. like: '../'

and if you want to rename your html file to index.html, you should use `gulp-rename` to do it before your `gulp.dest`

Comment: I have an existing  index.html in root , it just needs to be injected into , so i'm not even understanding what the purpose of the gulp.src even is ,  to me i am not trying to copy anything  just inject things , so the gulp.dest is a index.html ONE level up and gulp is not injecting into it